# Regex to extract multiple fields from pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern like this in a txt file:

```
["kiarix moreno","116224357500406255237","z120gbkosz2oc3ckv23bc10hhwrudlcjy04",1409770337,"com.youtube.www/watch?v\u003dp1JPKLa-Ofc:https","es"]
```

and I need a regex to extract each field in python. Every field can contain any character (not only alphanumeric) except for the 4th which is a long number. How can I do it? Many thanks.

EDIT: the file contains other html elements, that's why I can't parse it directly in a python List.

Comment: it seems like a list..

Comment: Is that a literal copy-paste of what's in your text file? You could just [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) it since it is already a valid python list of strings.

Comment: It is but the file in composed by other text. I can't simply import it as a list.

Comment: That looks like it's either JSON or Python 3 syntax (based on the unicode escape in the string). So use `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following provides three different options for getting your data:

```
>>> TEXT = '["kiarix moreno","116224357500406255237","z120gbkosz2oc3ckv23bc10hhwrudlcjy04",1409770337,"com.youtube.www/watch?v\u003dp1JPKLa-Ofc:https","es"]'
>>> import json, ast, re
>>> json.loads(TEXT)
['kiarix moreno', '116224357500406255237', 'z120gbkosz2oc3ckv23bc10hhwrudlcjy04', 1409770337, 'com.youtube.www/watch?v=p1JPKLa-Ofc:https', 'es']
>>> ast.literal_eval(TEXT)
['kiarix moreno', '116224357500406255237', 'z120gbkosz2oc3ckv23bc10hhwrudlcjy04', 1409770337, 'com.youtube.www/watch?v=p1JPKLa-Ofc:https', 'es']
>>> re.search(r'\["(?P<name>[^"]*)","(?P<number1>[^"]*)","(?P<data>[^"]*)",(?P<number2>\d*),"(?P<website>[^"]*)","(?P<language>[^"]*)"\]', TEXT).groupdict()
{'website': 'com.youtube.www/watch?v=p1JPKLa-Ofc:https', 'number2': '1409770337', 'language': 'es', 'data': 'z120gbkosz2oc3ckv23bc10hhwrudlcjy04', 'number1': '116224357500406255237', 'name': 'kiarix moreno'}
>>>
```

In particular, your regular expression would be the following: `r'\["(?P<name>[^"]*)","(?P<number1>[^"]*)","(?P<data>[^"]*)",(?P<number2>\d*),"(?P<website>[^"]*)","(?P<language>[^"]*)"\]'`

Answer (score 0):

```
"([^"]*")|(\d+)
```

You can try this.Grab the matches.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dK1xR4/5

Comment: `It is but the file in composed by other text.`

Answer (score 0):

you can
 1)open the file.
2)use **getline** to scan each line.
3)use **split()** function to split using "," and then use the resulting tuple/list
 however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to combine `re`, `try/except`, `ast.literal_eval` and file to read all possible elements, also to avoid any [ ] across several lines so readline won't work.

Here is my solution:

```
import re
import ast

# grab all possible lists in the file
found = re.findall(r'\[.*\]', open('yourfile.txt' ,'r').read())

for each in found:
    try:
        for el in ast.literal_eval(each):
            print el
    except SyntaxError:
        pass


kiarix moreno
116224357500406255237
z120gbkosz2oc3ckv23bc10hhwrudlcjy04
1409770337
com.youtube.www/watch?v\u003dp1JPKLa-Ofc:https
es
```